# We don't need [guidelines]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) looks like a meta-tag. It doesn't make sense for it to be the only tag, and doesn't help much with categorization. If a question is really *only* about guidelines, it's probably primarily opinion based anyway.

Its wiki is:

> rules or instructions that show or tell how something should be done

which screams primarily opinion-based questions. This makes it harmful because it draws questions that are not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I see, a few of those [tag:guidelines] questions are tagged with [tag:coding-style] as well. Some of these questions also look opinion-based (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330655)).

Comment: Various platforms have official UI guidelines that could be cited to support a fact-based answer... but maybe those questions belong on UX.SE instead.

Comment: You can add [tag:design-guidelines] to this as well.

Comment: Some might consider [tag:conventions] a synonym. For an argument for keeping one of these tags, please consider Microsoft's .NET [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its sub-article [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Similarly, consider [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I personally find that answers that cite authoritative sources such as these to be quite useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This tag is now burninated

Thanks to everyone that contributed to this task!

---

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments

Here are some easy links to get you started:

[guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guidelines)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguidelines%5D+closed%3Ano) 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguidelines%5D+closed%3Ayes) 0
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguidelines%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguidelines%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=guidelines)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!

If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room or leave a comment under this post.