# The backwards tag is backwards

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

64 questions are tagged as [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backwards). I don't think this tag confers any information, and there won't be any [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backwards) experts. Should the questions be untagged?

Comment: !trepxe sdrawkcab a m'I !tiaW

Comment: sdrawkcab tag is backwards?

Comment: No user has answered any more than 1 question tagged backwards.  It also has not tag wiki for potential uses.  It seems pretty pointless.

Comment: Yes, especially considering it should be *backward*, with no S...

Comment: ? åjsgnirK regoR-nrøjB@ oot uoY

Comment: Maybe it's the opposite of [tag:forward].

Comment: Obligatory PHP comment: Make it a synonym for [tag:php].

Comment: You should totally drop that and try jQuery

Comment: ![strepxe](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/backwards/topusers) drawkcab era erehT

Comment: @Trilarion  [tag:forward] fo etisoppo eht si [tag:drawrof]

Comment: Title suggestion: "*Revert [backwards]?*"

Comment: @TylerH: it depends whether you're using it as an adjective or an adverb, and whether you're using American English or Proper English: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/backward-versus-backwards

Comment: Reminds me of a question in The Impossible Quiz

Comment: @PaulR No, it's just like forward, onward, toward, untoward, etc. though the British are notorious for putting unnecessary letters in words...

Comment: @TylerH: I think it's more to do with Americans not really understanding the difference between adjectives and adverbs. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR You're mistaken, then :-) There's no need to add an s just because of the part of speech.

Comment: @TylerH: you're entitled to think different. ;-)

Comment: Or maybe, the gulf between [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22backward%22%2C%22backwards%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content="backward"%2C"backwards"&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3) english usage is sometimes overblown...

Comment: Maybe people are just confused about how to use [functional utility functions](https://github.com/Omega3k/backwards.js).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå ‮Oh yeah? Well, I can even make my username backwards! Beat that!

Comment: This question requires a backwards tag, ergo a backwards tag is required.

Comment: Backward tag is a drawback.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, only 7 questions remain in that tag right now.

It seems that a single <2k user decided to remove it on most if not all questions and was promptly approved by the queue.
Burnination is supposed to be a process of precise and careful cleaning - Closing off-topic questions, del-voting those for which the Roomba will have no effect and are useless or detrimental to the site, editing the last ones into shape while removing the tag.

The community or [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) hasn't had the chance to take this on and post regular status updates as was done [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318830/4174897) for the now-burninated [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) tag; as is described in [this process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md).

Next time, please refrain from any massive tag removal until community consensus is achieved and we can properly take care of the matter by improving the questions.

Comment: This should almost be a banner on all burnination requests.

Comment: Or what is done right now for [tag:guidelines] here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319601/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki We can use that until we get a banner ;)

Comment: First decide, then do.  The way the user did it was [tag:spɹɐʍʞɔɐq].

Comment: Sorry, this was not what I intended by asking my question. I have no idea burninations are properly handled, and I thought the appropriate persons would probably see my post. Should I post in the chat room next time, if I think a tag is worth deleting instead of opening a question?

Comment: @Kay Asking on Meta was the right thing to do. I don't really blame that misguided <2K user but rather the reviewers who let that pass. Do note that you can ask anything you want related to SO, moderation, or SOCVR in the room =)

Answer (score 38):

Giving people something to vote on:

---

It doesn't seem like that tag is very specific at all and each question has a more suitable tag already.

Comment: Just editing out the [tag:backward] tag from questions is probably not a good idea since burninations are also good opportunities to remove a lot of off-topic questions from the site or improve them with edits. [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) has come up with a [process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process) that allows a clean tag removal. For example, many of these questions could probably be closed as dupes of canonical posts.

Comment: This answer has led to at least one <2k rep user spam the edit review queue with needless "burnination edits". **Please do not** "Go ahead and start editing out the [backwards] tag"

Comment: Very sorry. I was just trying to give people something to vote on.  I have edited out that part.

Comment: It seems the damage has been done during the 11 hours this was up =/

Comment: i might as well just delete this answer right?

Comment: Your call. I wouldn't worry about it :)