# User filling Suggestion Edit review queue with tag-only edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A user has several edits in the Edit Suggestion queue right now (most of which ignore other issues with the relevant post), where they only remove the [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backwards) tag.

The edit comment which is pasted with all their suggestions:

> Removed backward tag, as it is being burninated: [The backwards tag is backwards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319518/backwards-tag-is-backwards?cb=1)

The harmful part (aside from not addressing other content issues) is there hasn't been a consensus reached regarding the tag, and it has not yet moved forward in the new [burnination process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

I've used a few of my reviews to reject their suggestions, using the "causes harm" field to offer a custom response. I see other active users from Meta have done the same. Unfortunately a few suggestions have also been approved.

Is there a better way to educate the user without having to reject each suggestion? Is there a mod tool which rejects-all?

---

(edit) Similar discussion (possible dupe?): [How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users?rq=1)

(update) All of said User's reviews have been taken care of. Though I do see this was handled a bit late. At a glance they have submitted 50 - 60 other "burnination" edits, [most in the past hour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735775/ashish-ahuja-%E3%83%84?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: Slightly related: Is there a feature request to have any "Causes harm" reviews to be displayed above above the suggestion to all reviewers?

Comment: Or even allowing me to copy an existing "Causes harm" rejection reason like in the close vote queue.

Comment: With 64 questions at the time of writing the Meta question (so, before this user went on a spree), that tag may not need the burnination process. The problem is if users _only_ remove the tag, and fail to address other issues.

Comment: Looks like the meta-answer in the burnination request thread (which may have served as the source of inspiration for the editing user) has been updated.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you're right, the main issue are the edits which don't address other issues in the post. The burnination relevance really only serves as the cause for this particular scenario. I suppose the "better way outside of rejecting each suggestion" question is my point.

Comment: I think there's a good feature request in here somewhere. Something about giving more feedback to <2K editors. Although as I understand it, if an edit is rejected, they are warned when suggesting their next edit.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yep, that's my understanding as well, though it doesn't seem to impact already-submitted suggestions.

Comment: I believe you can always @-ping a suggester; and you can definitely ping them on a post where the edit was accepted.

Comment: @Undo I knew you could ping editors once the suggestion / edit is approved/made, but I didn't think that would work with suggestors.

Comment: It doesn't work with suggestors _unless_ the edit is approved. @-notifying someone _only_ works if they've interacted with the post, and a pending or rejected suggested edit does not count. From the [FAQ:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/266735) _"Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions)."_ cc @Undo

Comment: @Kendra Good to know, thanks. Looks like the user in question got enough of them approved that they should be fairly easy to contact.

Comment: I'm also seeing around 60 total "burnination" edits made by the user, more than half of which had already been approved. Seems we caught this a bit late.